# AdMob Native Advanced Ads in an iOS Get Received invalid response

Tags: iphone, swift, admob, native-ads

i have download google admob test project.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/NativeAdvancedExample

this project successfully run but not show advertising.

And alway call `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` method

and Received invalid response.

```
 2018-06-05 11:55:10.072277+0530 NativeAdvancedExample[3880:87303] <Google:HTML> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.tracking_urls_and_actions') 

<GADAdLoader: 0x6040002a7c20> failed with error: Request Error: Received invalid response.
```

Can anybody figure out what's wrong with??

Comment: i have use xcode Version 9.4.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are using by default the supplied Test ID from Google..!

```
  use "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"
```